# How to send HTML formatted auto-activation email after user registration

Tags: php, html

I am having an issue on how to make the automated activation email that a user gets after registering on our site be in **"HTML format"** instead of a **"Plain-Text format"**. I practically don't know what to do or where to look into.

Comment: please tell us what have you tried to do. Have you coded anything?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for the link. That really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP `mail()` function to send email once you have it setup on your server.

In order to get `mail()` to send html formatted emails, you need to set the **content type** and **charset** in the header of the email.

What's below is taken from [php.net, here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), which is a great resource for learning about the `mail()` function and php in general.

```
<?php
// Multiple recipients
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma

// Subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// Message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content -->
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```